# Open second view

Tags: ios, swift

I try to check of a user was successfully logged in. If this be true, then not the login screen shut be loaded. The TerminView would be loaded.
[image]

Here is the function in the LoginViewController (I wanna use this function also, when the user login successfully after press the "Login"-Button)

```
func checkIfLoggedIn() -> Void {

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent(K.login.file)?.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TerminView") as UIViewController, animated: true)

    }
}
```

In the storyboard I give the TerminViewController also the id: TerminView

Here is the call of this function in the AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {

        LoginViewController().checkIfLoggedIn()
}
```

Where is my misstake?

Comment: Why dont you use NSUserDefaults to save if the user is logged?

Comment: call checkIfLoggedIn in viewDidLoad of login view controller

Comment: Save login status of user in `UserDefaults` and check in app delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching` if the user is logged in set the root controller as `TerminViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You need to change rootViewController with login flag

```
func isUserLoggedIN() -> Bool {
        var struserID: String? = ""
        if  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"LoginKey") != nil {
            struserID  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"LoginKey") as! String?
        }
        return struserID!.characters.count > 0 ? true : false
    }
```

**Check as below**

```
if self.isUserLoggedIN() {
     let navLog: UINavigationController? = Constant.StoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginNavBar") as? UINavigationController
     window?.rootViewController = navLog
            }
else{
   // set another ViewController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to handled this in app delegate class, than based on login status. you need to set **root view of the navigation controller**. I think for better approach to handle this situation after the first sucessfull login u need to store result in NSUserdefault. Second time check this userdefault and accordingly set root view of your navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I will try to search for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give the instance of loginViewController to appdelegate
use this in appDelegate

```
let loginVC: LoginViewController?
```

this in viewDidload of LoginViewController

```
    let appDele = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDele.loginVC = self
```

and this in application did finish launching

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if(loginVc != nil){
    loginVC.checkIfLoggedIn()    }}
```

it is recommended that use userdefaults but if you want to continue with this solution then try this

Answer (score 0):

In Your app delegate you must set the root controller. As per your requirement see below code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //Main your storyboard identifier

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Your_Storyboard_identifier", bundle: nil)
        var rootController:UIViewController

        //Retrieve Login Status if user is logged in or not

        let loginStatus: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "LoginStatus")

        // if login status is true show TerminViewController else LoginViewController

        if loginStatus == true {
            //Your TerminViewController

            rootController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TerminViewController")
        }
        else{
            //Your LoginViewController

            rootController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")

        }

        //setting root view controller

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootController


        return true

    }
```

On Login Button click save the user login status in `UserDefaults`

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

//Store user login status in userdefaults and check it in app delegate when the user open your app again.            

UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "LoginStatus")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

//Your Logic here ..
// On user login you might be navigating to TermViewController.
}
```